# Searching for a substring within multiple lines of a file

Tags: c++, string, search, substring

I have a text file "dna.txt" I know how to read from the file and count the occurences of each letter (A, T, C, or G, but I have no idea how to iterate through the multiple line to have all combinations of "AT" which would be a substring within dna.txt. I have no idea where to start. I read about strstr but have no idea how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: if you know how to read A, T, C and G ... then just store occurrence of A in a variable and then read next character ..if it is T then you found your combination of AT .. just do whatever you want to do with it.. maybe increase the count of its occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **ifstream.getlinegetline (char* buffer, int count )** to read the file line by line.
And if I have got you correctly in case of finding the count of "AT", go on finding char "A" and every time you come across "A", check if next character is "T" and increase the count.